# DIV Positioning to the left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble positioning the `.menubox div` (red)... As I would like it to sit nicely beside the left `.menu div`. Instead, it stubbornly refuses to move from below the `.menu`. In short, I want to position these side by side, so I'm at fault, I know, just a push on the right direction would greatly be appreciated.

Please see the link to my [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f6Fb/106/)

html:

```
<div id="parent_container">
    <div id='prod_cont'>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="menuitem" href="#smPlates">Product Preview 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="menuitem" href="#salads">Product Preview 2</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="menuitem" href="#burgers">Product Preview 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="menuitem" href="#desserts">Product Preview 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <!-- P1 -->
    <div class="menubox" id="smPlates">
        <p>Product Detail 1</p>
    </div>
    <!-- P2 -->
    <div class="menubox" id="salads">
        <p>Product Detail 2</p>
    </div>
    <!-- P3 -->
    <div class="menubox" id="burgers">
        <p>Product Detail 3</p>
    </div>
    <!-- P4 -->
    <div class="menubox" id="desserts">
        <p>Product Detail 4</p>
    </div>
</div>

CSS:

#parent_container {
    height:700px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#66CCCC;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:20px;
}

#prod_cont {
    width:255px;
    height:410px;
    background-color:#fff; 
    padding:10px;
}
.menuitem {
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FFFFE0;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-right:5px;

}


.menubox {
    width:30%;
    height:260px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 25px;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    text-align:right;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding:10px;

}
```

Thank you kindly for solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the `float: left` to `#prod_cont` and `.menubox`, do not forget to clear the floats.

You can use css such as `clear: both` to a div after `.menubox` class.

Answer (score 1):

Both your `prod_cont` and `.menubox` need `float:left`.

Add the following:

```
#prod_cont, .menubox {
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7f6Fb/113/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```css
#parent_container>div {display:inline-block;vertical-align:top}
```

Comment: This won't work since the jQuery overwrites the `display` rule with an inline `display:block`.

Comment: It's its peculiar way of implementing the `hide` function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove width from `#prod_cont`

and add `float:left` to `.menubox`

The final styles will be

```
#prod_cont {
    height:410px;
    background-color:#fff; 
    padding:10px;
}
.menuitem {
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FFFFE0;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-right:5px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("" + relatedDivID).fadeToggle("slow", "linear",function(){

 }).css({display:'inline-block'});
```

add the following into your current

```
.prod_cont{display:inline-block;}
.menubox{vertical-align:top}
```

here's a quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f6Fb/119/)